# Some doubts in the proof that $[0,1]$ is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

There is this proof about the fact that the set $[0,1]$ is uncountable. I found the first few reasoning in the proof does not really make sense but I'm not sure whether I am correct.

I will write the entire proof for reference:

Suppose $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ was a complete list of real numbers in $[0,1]$. Assume $a_1\neq0$.

Form a subsequence as follows:
$b_1=a_1$,
$b_2=a_{k(2)}$, $k(2)$ is the least integer $m>1$ such that $a_m<a_1$,
$b_3=a_{k(3)}$, $k(3)$ is the least integer $m>k(2)$ such that $a_m>a_{k(2)}$,
$b_4=a_{k(4)}$, $k(4)$ is the least integer $m>k(3)$ such that $a_m<a_{k(3)}$,
and so on.

Then $b_{2n}$ is an increasing sequence, $b_{2n}\to B=a_N$.
Note $a_{2n}<B<a_{2l+1}$ $\forall n,l$.

Suppose $k(n)<N<k(n+1)$. Then we would have chosen $b_{n+1}=aN=B$. Contradiction.

What I think is wrong is the claim that $b_{2n}$ is an increasing sequence. A counterexample that I can think of is: $b_1=89.5, b_2=76.43, b_3=2937, b_4=2.3$. Obviously, $b_4<b_2$. Is my counterexample wrong?

Could anyone please point my mistake? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find that proof? Are you sure you copied it exactly? For example, it really says $a_{2n}\lt B\lt a_{2l+1}$ not $b_{2n}\lt B\lt b_{2l+1}$? And $k(3)$ is the least integer $m\gt k(2)$ such that $a_m\gt a_{k(2)},$ not the least $m\gt k(2)$ such that $a_{k(2)}\lt a_m\lt a_1$?

Comment: Note that the sequence $(a_n)_n$ consists of elements in $[0, 1]$; your list of elements $b_n$ does not lie within that set.

Comment: Apart from the problem pointed out by @SimonRose (which is easily fixed), your reasoning is correct: $b_{2n}$ is not in general an increasing sequence.

Comment: You need to amend the def'ns so that   $a_{k_{n+2}}$ is between $a_{k_n}$ and $a_{k_{n+1}}.$

Answer (score 2):

There does seem to be something missing in the proof.
You are right, the conditions do not guarantee an increasing sequence,
and as far as I can see they do not even guarantee that the
subsequence $b_{2n}$ converges.

If you have copied the proof exactly, perhaps you are working from
a copy that is itself an imperfect copy of the correct proof.
I think it could be patched up by requiring an additional inequality
for each term starting with the third:
\begin{align}
b_1&=a_1,  \\
b_2&=a_{k(2)} \text{ where $k(2)$ is the least integer $m>1$ such that $a_m<a_1$,}\\ 
b_3&=a_{k(3)} \text{ where $k(3)$ is the least integer $m>k(2)$ such that $a_1>a_m>a_{k(2)}$,}  \\
b_4&=a_{k(4)} \text{ where $k(4)$ is the least integer $m>k(3)$ such that $a_{k(2)}<a_m<a_{k(3)}$,}
\end{align}

That is, each term of $b_i$ is the next term of $a_m$ that is *between*
the previous two terms of $b_i$.